# Java RMI Connection Refused to Host Exception

Tags: java

I am developing a simple server based calculation program in java and rmi. However, The Server is not initializing with the following exception.

```
Initializing Server
Remote Server Error:Connection refused to host: 192.168.1.3; nested exception is:
    java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
```

I have turned off my microsoft firewall. After that also, the problem persists. Here is the code I am running :

```
  import java.rmi.*;
    import java.rmi.Naming.*;
    import java.rmi.server.*;
    import java.rmi.registry.*;
    import java.net.*;
    import java.util.*;

    interface mathInterface extends Remote
    {
     public int add(int a,int b) throws RemoteException;
     public int subt(int a,int b) throws RemoteException;
     public int mult(int a,int b) throws RemoteException;
     public int div(int a,int b) throws RemoteException;
    }

    public class mathServer extends UnicastRemoteObject implements mathInterface
    {
                public mathServer() throws RemoteException
                {
                                System.out.println("Initializing Server");
    }
    public int add(int a,int b)
    {
                                return(a+b);
                }
                public int subt(int a,int b)
                    {
                                                return(a-b);
                }
                public int mult(int a,int b)
                    {
                                                return(a*b);
                }
                public int div(int a,int b)
                    {
                                                return(a/b);
                }
                public static void main(String args[])
                {
                                try
                                {
                                mathServer ms=new mathServer();
                                java.rmi.Naming.rebind("MathServ",ms);
                                System.out.println("Server Ready");
                    }
                    catch(RemoteException RE)
                    {
                                                System.out.println("Remote Server Error:"+ RE.getMessage());
                                                System.exit(0);
                                }
                                catch(MalformedURLException ME)
                                {
                                                System.out.println("Invalid URL!!");
                                }
                }
}
```

Kindly help me sort out this issue.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't started the RMI Registry.